# Data member alters itself automatically when a member function is called

Tags: c++, insert, binary-tree

I"m trying to build a rudimentary Binary Tree for learning purposes. I use three classes:

```
template<typename Elem>
class Node


template<Typename Elem>
class BinaryTreet;
```

and a nested iterator class

```
template<typename Elem>
BinaryTreet<Elem>::iterator;
```

The Node and BinaryTreet classes are implemented like this:

```
template<typename Elem>
class Node {
public:
    Elem Key = Key();
    Node* Parent = nullptr;
    Node* Left = nullptr;
    Node* Right = nullptr;
    void operator=(Node<Elem> x);
    Node();
    Node(Elem x,Node* p = nullptr, Node* l = nullptr, Node* r = nullptr); //both constructors are implemented in the standard manner

};

template<typename Elem>
class BinaryTreet { 

private:
    class iterator; //Node<Elem>*

public:
    BinaryTreet(std::initializer_list<Elem> lst);
    void insert(Node<Elem> z);
    iterator root;
};
```

with the constructor implemented as:

```
template<typename Elem>
BinaryTreet<Elem>::BinaryTreet(std::initializer_list<Elem> lst){
    for (Node<Elem> x : lst) {
        this->insert(x);
    }
}
```

The nested iterator class holds a pointer to the node it is supposed to be pointing to and a dereference operator that returns a reference to that node:

```
template<typename Elem>
class BinaryTreet<Elem>::iterator {
public:
    Node<Elem>* curr = nullptr;

    Node<Elem>& operator*(); //return *curr
    void operator=(BinaryTreet<Elem>::iterator x);
    bool operator ==(const iterator& b);
    bool operator != (const iterator& b);
};
```

The insert function, uses the iterators. After walking through with the debugger, I noticed that the call to this function alters the root variable of the BinaryTreet it was calledcfor, before the first line of the function is even executed.

```
template<typename Elem>
void BinaryTreet<Elem>::insert(Node<Elem> z){
    iterator y;
    iterator x = root; //the BinaryTreet::iterator::operator =() just copies the curr pointer's value
    while (x.curr != nullptr) {
        y.curr = x.curr;
        if ((*x).Key < z.Key) {  //*x is a Node<Elem>&, so *x.Key is supposed to return Node<Elem>::Key's value
            x.curr = (*x).Left; 
        }
        else {
            x.curr = (*x).Right;
        }
    }

    z.Parent = y.curr;

    if (y.curr == nullptr) {
        root.curr = &z; //Node<Elem>::operator = (Node<Elem> x)
    }
    else {
        if (z.Key < (*y).Key) {
            (*y).Left = &z;
        }
        else {
            (*y).Right = &z;
        }
    }
}
```

So, when the insert() function is called in BinaryTreet(initializer_list lst) constructor - say with a list {3,2,15,14,1,9,6} (Elem is int here) - the first iteration sets the iterator root's curr value to a Node with Key value of 3. But, in the second iteration of the for-loop in the constructor, the Key value of the node pointed to by the root iterator's curr pointer is set to 2 before the first line of the function is executed. Which messes up the rest of the function.

I don't understand how the root variable is being altered by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing pointers to objects which have been destroyed. Your insert function essentially does this

```
template<typename Elem>
void BinaryTreet<Elem>::insert(Node<Elem> z){
    ...
    some_pointer = &z;
}
```

But `z` no longer exists when the `insert` function exits, so you are left with a pointer to an object which has been destroyed. This is undefined behaviour. In effect what is happening is that the memory that was occupied by your root node is being reused for the next node, so the root appears to change.

The answer is to use dynamic memory allocation (i.e. to create your nodes with `new`), so that your nodes are not destroyed when your function is exited.

Comment: I added the line `Node<Elem>* s  = new Node<Elem>{x}` inside the for-loop in BinaryTreet's constructor and altered the insert() function call to `insert(*s)`. But I'm still getting the same behavior of root automatically being set to a node with Key 2 at the beginning of the second iteration.

Comment: @CharlieKeith Well you still have the same problem. You are taking a pointer to the parameter of `insert` and that parameter is destroyed when the `insert` function is exited. Change `insert` so that it's parameter is a pointer. Don't store pointers to local variables.

Comment: Passing as a pointer worked. Would passing a reference also achieve the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but there's no point. You have to store a pointer, and you have to dynamically allocate, so what's the point in converting a pointer to a reference only to convert it back to a pointer again? Actaully the best thing to do would be to change your `insert` routine to take an `Elem` as it's argument. Then you could allocate the `Node<Elem>` inside the insert routine, and set the key for the node using the passed Elem parameter. That makes sense because the node is being allocated where it is needed, in the insert function, not in the function that calls insert.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++11 example of what the other answer is saying about dynamic memory allocation. I think this is generally what you were getting at with your code.

We needed to establish who actually owns the node objects and what their lifetime is. Everything now belongs to the root node, which belongs to the tree. Non-owning relationships are represented with raw pointers.

```
template<typename Elem>
class Node {
public:
  using raw_pointer = Node<Elem>*;
  using owned_pointer = std::unique_ptr<Node<Elem>>;
  using reference = Node<Elem>&;

  static owned_pointer make_root_node(Elem key) {
    return owned_pointer{ new Node<Elem>(key) };
  }

  Elem Key{};

  // Does not default initialize to null, so if(Parent) may not do what you expect
  raw_pointer Parent = nullptr;
  // Each node owns its children. 
  // The unique_ptr default initializes to "empty" and implicitly
  // converts to false, so if(Left) works as you expect.
  owned_pointer Left;
  owned_pointer Right;

  // A node without a key is no longer meaningful because we don't have to
  // construct any placeholder nodes.
  // I actually forgot to ever set the parent in my original answer, which is
  // a perfect example of why accepting null just because the root doesn't have
  // a parent is a bad idea.
  // Better yet, have a dummy parent for the root and hold a reference.
  Node(Elem key, reference parent)
    : Key{key}, Parent{&parent}
  {}

  // By using unique_ptr we've deleted the copy constructor and
  // the copy assignment operator (operator=).
  //
  // There's two things you'll have to consider if you want those operations:
  // 1. What if this node already owns children? What happens to those when we fill
  //    it with new values?
  // 2. If we're copying from another node, do we also own its children? What if
  //    we try to delete them after it does? This is why you can't copy unique_ptr.
  //    If you want to assign this node from another one then you'll have to move
  //    the Left and Right members out of the other node and take responsibility
  //    for destructing them.

private:
  // If you want to make a node with no parent you must express your intent
  // by calling make_root_node()
  Node(Elem key)
    : Key{key}
  {}
};

template<typename Elem>
class BinaryTree {
public:
  using key_type = Elem;
  using node_type = Node<Elem>;
  using owned_node_pointer = typename node_type::owned_pointer;
  using raw_node_pointer = typename node_type::raw_pointer;

  // The caller doesn't need to be exposed to our internal workings
  void insert(key_type new_entry);

private:
  // The tree owns the root node
  owned_node_pointer root;
};


template<typename Elem>
void BinaryTree<Elem>::insert(key_type new_entry) {
  // The root is initially an empty leaf
  if (root == nullptr) {
    root = node_type::make_root_node(new_entry);
    return;
  }
  // The iterator was really just a pointer.
  // "iterator" brings some semantics with it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator
  raw_node_pointer it = nullptr;
  raw_node_pointer it_down = root.get();

  // We avoid repeating this logic
  auto choose_branch = [](const key_type& new_key, const raw_node_pointer it) -> owned_node_pointer& {
    return (new_key <= it->Key) ? it->Left : it->Right;
  };

  while (it_down) {
    it = it_down;
    it_down = choose_branch(new_entry, it).get();
  }

  auto& destination_leaf = choose_branch(new_entry, it);

  // Here we actually allocate and construct a new node. At this point it's owned
  // by this function, and when this function ends and the variable goes
  // out of scope the node will be destroyed.
  //
  // auto new_node = std::make_unique<node_type>(new_entry);
  // destination_leaf = std::move(new_node);
  //
  // By moving the unique_ptr our copy of it (new_node) is now empty 
  // and the object it points to is owned by the node in destination_leaf. 
  // When that owner node is destructed its unique_ptr members will also be
  // destructed, and their members too, cleaning up the whole subtree.
  // Just letting the tree root go out of scope will destruct all of the nodes.
  //
  // see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr
  //
  // The following is equivalent to the block above, but instead of placing
  // the unique_ptr in a temporary and moving out of that we directly assign
  // the temporary to the destination. I believe the compiler will construct
  // the unique_ptr at the site of destination_leaf and avoid any move.
  //
  assert(it && "we don't have a parent, or the root is null--this is a bug");
  destination_leaf = std::make_unique<node_type>(new_entry, *it);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to explain the concept in such detail.